# How can I trigger mouse up at the specific position

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I tried to trigger mousedown event at the specific position using jQuery.

What I need is to implement mousedown event at the specified coordinates and mouseup event also.

So I am going to implement mouse drag event automatically when I click any button.
Is it possible on canvas?

This is my attempt

```
$('#clickMe').click(function() {
  $("#map-canvas").trigger("mousedown",  { which: 1, pageX: 1057, pageY: 770 });
  $("#map-canvas").trigger("mouseup", { which: 1, pageX: 370, pageY: 541 });
  $("#map-canvas").off("mousedown").on("mousedown", function (e) {
    console.log('#### DEBUG CLICK: ', e);
  });
  $("#map-canvas").off("mouseup").on("mouseup", function (e) {
    console.log('#### DEBUG CLICK EVENT: ', e); // fixme
  });
});
```

Trigger`s action is okay.
But I can not mousedown event at the expectation position.
[image: My Issue]

How can I implement it?
Thanks.

Comment: Why you need such functionality for?

Comment: I want to view the screen auto move when I open my project.
What is not sure for you?

Comment: So, use `mousemove` event (or other recognizable event). Why emulate `mousedown` and `mouseup` when it doesn't happend.

Comment: It doesn`t work also.

Comment: @MMDM I'm writing automated tests. Having this functionality would help me right now

Comment: Ever figure this one out?